# How to turn a function item into a function pointer in rust

Tags: rust

So the target type is:

```rust
pub type SkittleModuleCommand = fn(ctx: Context, msg: Message, args: Vec<String>) -> dyn Future<Output = Result<()>>
```

But the rust compiler says that a function im trying to pass as an argument is the incorrect type.
The error:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:17:37
   |
17 |     module.register_command("ping", ping);
   |            ----------------         ^^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
   |            |
   |            arguments to this method are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(serenity::prelude::Context, serenity::model::channel::Message, Vec<_>) -> (dyn std::future::Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>> + 'static)`
                 found fn item `fn(serenity::prelude::Context, serenity::model::channel::Message, Vec<_>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>> {commands::ping::exec}`
   = note: when the arguments and return types match, functions can be coerced to function pointers
note: method defined here
  --> /home/mcorange/@Projects/rust/autistic-bot/src/lib.rs:62:12
   |
62 |     pub fn register_command(&mut self, name: &str, comm: SkittleModuleCommand) {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
warning: `skittle-bot-core-module` (lib) generated 4 warnings
```

The whole project is on [github](https://github.com/MCorange99/skittle-bot)

Also, heres the minimum Reproductible Example:

```rust
use std::{future::Future, collections::HashMap};


pub type SkittleModuleCommand = fn(a: usize) -> dyn Future<Output = ()>;

pub async fn module_fn(a: usize) {}

fn main() {
    let mut mod_hm: HashMap<String, SkittleModuleCommand> = HashMap::new();

    mod_hm.insert(String::from(""), module_fn);

}
```

I tried using transmute but i cant get the wrong type right.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also, please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And put everything necessary here. External links are not enough.

Comment: If you're a beginner (and you're a beginner as you didn't even specify the function type correctly), then you should never reach for transmute or unsafe code in the first place.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Fixed both

Comment: A `dyn Trait` is not the same thing as an `impl Trait`. In isolation one can be coerced into the other, but a function can't be coerced to another signature with a different return type. That and returning a `dyn Trait` is not practically allowed, you would hit other issues beyond this type mismatch. You probably want `Box<dyn Trait>` or similar instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `-> dyn Future<Output = Result<()>>`

Returning a raw dyn generally doesn't make sense, it's [a DST](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html?highlight=Unsized%20Type#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait) which is extremely difficult to use when not behind a pointer.

Furthermore as the error message tells you, you're trying to return an `impl Future`, which is a completely different thing (it's a specific but opaque type implementing the trait).

What you need to do is:

1. change your type such that the `dyn Future` is in a `Box`, that will actually let you manipulate and return one

   ```
   fn(ctx: Context, msg: Message, args: Vec<String>) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<()>>>;
   ```
2. return that from your function, I'm not actually sure it's possible to do that directly using either built-in syntax or the `futures` module (somebody else might know) but you can just desugar your async function:

   ```
   pub fn exec(ctx: Context, msg: Message, _: Vec<String>) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<()>>> {
       Box::new(async move {
           msg.reply_mention(ctx, "Pong!").await?;
           Ok(())
       })
   }
   ```

> I tried using transmute but i cant get the wrong type right.

That is very rarely the right solution to a compilation error, especially if you're randomly throwing shit at the wall.

Comment: They probably need `Pin<Box>`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, kinda. I cannot use await on the function.

```rust
let a = (fun.1)(ctx, msg, argv).let b = (*a).await;
```

The error:

```rust
the size for values of type `dyn std::future::Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>>` cannot be known at compilation time
the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn std::future::Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>>`
required for `dyn std::future::Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>>` to implement `std::future::IntoFuture`
```

Comment: welp anyways it looks like im gonna be rewriting the module part so this was unneeded, but the fix worked.